# What does "variable access definition in wrong order" mean in Checkstyle?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I run checkstyle on my **Java** code and get this error:

> variable access definition in wrong order

Can somebody tell me what that means?

Comment: post the relevant lines of code, theres not really much anyone ca don with the info you've given so far

Comment: java code where I am getting this checkstyle violation error-
static final String WORKFLOWNAME = "WORKFLOWNAME";

Comment: Please put the problem code in your original question (not a comment).  And if you found a resolution using an answer, please put the exact restructured code in your answer or in the comment of that helpful answer.  SOF is a community and helping others with your question is a part of it.  If you do those things, I'll upvote your question.

Answer (score 79):

Could it be that you have declaration order configured in CheckStyle? Take a look at 
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#DeclarationOrder

In that link, you will notice that it says ...
*According to Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language , the parts of a class or interface declaration should appear in the following order:

Class (static) variables.
First the public class variables,
then the protected,
then package level (no access modifier), and
then the private.

Instance variables.
First the public class variables,
then the protected,
then package level (no access modifier), and
then the private Constructors Methods*

Comment: +1 -- didn't know about this code convention. Learned something new. Good!

Comment: Good answer, bad Checkstyle rule! I've worked in many Java codebases that follow the exact opposite order (private, package, protected, public). Sigh...

Comment: what about final variable ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is a little late for answering this question but in my case i had some thing like that:

```
public final class ClassA{
    private ClassA() {
    }
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassA.class);
}
```

and after i changed the order to:

```
public final class ClassA{
    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassA.class);
    private ClassA() {
    }
}
```

my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have something like `static public int`. Normally, that would be written as `public static int`.

Comment: try `final static String WFN = "val";`

Comment: hmm, checked and static final String is the [correct default order](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#78091) section 8.3.1...

Comment: @Manoj rearrange the class in the order that the code conventions dictate. IMHO, this is not a major issue -- actually i would just go in and modify the CheckStyle configuration by taking out the DeclarationOrder module.

Comment: @Manoj, If that works, you can (nudge nudge) go in upvote my answer and mark it as the correct answer later :)

Comment: @Sai He does not have enough "points" to upvote. I did a +1 on the question -- which might get him enough points to upvote and accept etc.

Comment: @user294280 he can always accept, although 15 (which he has thanks to you ;) ) is the minimum to upvote